# Javascript For Each Object inside Array containing a property that is Array check If Value Matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

For each object inside this array containing userHandle array loop through that array(userHandle one) and check if one of those values matches some string I choose called uid.  How to write that code in Javascript?

```
Array [
      Object {
        "avatar": null,
        "hugCount": 2,
        "id": 35,
        "liked": false,
        "name": "fhfdhdhf",
        "text": "Yoho",
        "timestamp": 1610471860157,
        "uid": "FOgepuJqxXfkHxI8OAV2KMWodXo1",
      },
      Object {
        "avatar": null,
        "hugCount": 1,
        "id": 34,
        "liked": true,
        "mood": 2,
        "name": "fhfdhdhf",
        "text": "I'm fine today.",
        "timestamp": 1607943705709,
        "uid": "FOgepuJqxXfkHxI8OAV2KMWodXo1",
        "userHandle": Array [
          "Aw8AUj1mPkON1Fd1s6LhkNETHfb2",
          "LrIwIx9I1xQBJ7aeCSrinpEaDP53",
        ],
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var uid = "LrIwIx9I1xQBJ7aeCSrinpEaDP53";

yourArray.forEach(function(item, _){
  return item['userHandle']?.indexOf(uid);
});
```

The '?' is to make sure your Object contains the 'userHandle' property

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you need... and below you can see how to use it.

You need to pass the value you are looking for, and the array with the information.

```
function findInUserHandle(uidValue, array)
{
  return array.reduce
  (
    (acum, current) => 
      current.userHandle && current.userHandle.indexOf(uidValue) !== -1 || acum,
      false
  )
}

let array = [
  {
     "avatar": null,
     "hugCount": 2,
     "id": 35,
     "liked": false,
     "name": "fhfdhdhf",
     "text": "Yoho",
     "timestamp": 1610471860157,
     "uid": "FOgepuJqxXfkHxI8OAV2KMWodXo1",
   },
  {
     "avatar": null,
     "hugCount": 1,
     "id": 34,
     "liked": true,
     "mood": 2,
     "name": "fhfdhdhf",
     "text": "I'm fine today.",
     "timestamp": 1607943705709,
     "uid": "FOgepuJqxXfkHxI8OAV2KMWodXo1",
     "userHandle":[
       "Aw8AUj1mPkON1Fd1s6LhkNETHfb2",
       "LrIwIx9I1xQBJ7aeCSrinpEaDP53",
     ],
   }
 ]
 
findInUserHandle('something', array) //?  false
findInUserHandle('Aw8AUj1mPkON1Fd1s6LhkNETHfb2', array) //? true
findInUserHandle('mood', array) //?  false
```

Comment: CamelCase is for standards bodies, use underscores between words.